# Installing nvidia GTX 860M drivers

Tags: nvidia, lenovo

I have been trying to install the drivers for my Lenovo y50 graphics card, GTX 860M but nothing seams to work! There are some guides on the net, but everyone of them make my screen go black on start and I have to reinstall every time! Can someone help me out?

Comment: You need to install the drivers before you start the xserver. I would suggest researching which driver works with your GPU, and installing it before you install any GUI. So, you could install the Ubuntu Server Edition, which has no graphical interface. Than you could install the correct driver, and than install Unity of Gnome Desktop (whatever you prefer). Another work around would be to press ctl+alt+F1 the second Ubuntu boots up, and installing the correct driver from tty1.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The problem is that there does not seam to be any correct drivers for this card. When I search for the name I get like 10 different drivers to install. I tried the tty1 method but still the drivers that are around are not working.

Comment: You may have to blacklist the default drivers to prevent them from being loaded and causing problems.

Comment: I have the same problem and I tried  (1)instaling from ctrl_alt+f1 , (2) instaling with .sh , (3) instaling via the edgers repository, I tried every possible driver in this repository and all of them don't work. Before when I was on linux-mint I managed to install the driver. Back then I was with much newer kernel , but I don't know if the old kernel is the reason  not to work now. I don't know how to check which driver has been loaded ? And what would help to blacklist it?

Comment: This is what I do every time trying to install the driver (only the first time adding the repository): (1)sudo service lightdm stop
(open a terminal with F1)
(2)sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
(3)sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
(4)sudo apt-get update
(5)sudo apt-get install nvidia-340

Comment: try this one man: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/810964/linux/black-screen-after-prime-select-nvidia-and-log-out-using-v346-35-drivers/2/   it worked for me :). Today is my lucky day. So installing via edgers seems not to work.